# What is the best way to structure an ethnographic study?

Tags: methodology, hci

I'm writing an ethnographic study for a human computer interaction module and I understand all the processes of conducting ethnography.

I am unsure of how to structure my study. Is it conventional to have it in an essay format, or are case studies preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used ethnography for similar purposes several times. Structuring the interviews so that you are an apprentice and your subject plays the role of a master artisan works well.

The book, "Contextual Design" by Beyer and Holtzblatt provides several modeling techniques for expressing the information in some ways that add significantly to essay.

[http://www.amazon.com/Contextual-Design-Customer-Centered-Technologies-ebook/dp/B003VM7GEC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382970418&sr=8-1&keywords=holtzblatt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VM7GEC)